# Form-data-processing PHP called via AJAX in same file as <form>?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

When you use HTML forms, I learned it's 'elegant' to process the data in the same file eg. `<?php if isset($_POST['submit'] doSomething(); ?> ... <form action="" method="POST">`

But what if I want to send the data via ajax? Do I put the `doSomething()` in a separate php-file that I send the data to or should I also put it in the same file and just `exit()` before the actual site content begins (if it has been called by ajax)? I think that way it would be a lot easier to make the site also work with JS disabled.

I understand that both ways would work, but I'm wondering what's considered cleaner and will lead to less errors.

Here's example code to explain what I mean:

```
/* example.php */
<?php
if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    doSomething( $_POST['foo'] );
    if( !isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] ) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="foo" id="foo">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $('form').submit( function( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $.post( 'example.php', { submit: '', foo: $('#foo').val() } );

    } );
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is that a good and maintainable approach?

Comment: always make another file of ajax if you are doing it in core php than make a file ajax.php etc. and then make a function and call that function. ajax call in same file is not good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you use HTML forms, I learned it's 'elegant' to process the data in the same file

Not really. It's a good idea to process the data on the same **URL**.

The primary advantage of this is that when users submit bad data, it allows you to easily show the form again, prepopulated with the data from the last attempt, and with additional error messages.

Putting everything into a single file isn't such a good idea. It's generally better to split things up. For example:

```
include("process_form_data.php");
include("form.php");
include("result.php");

$errors = array();

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $errors = process_form_data();
    if (count($errors)) {
         show_form();
    } else {
         show_result();
    }
} else {
    show_form();
}
```

This is usually simplified by the use of an MVC framework of similar.

---

> But what if I want to send the data via ajax?

Then it matters less. You never need to show the whole form in response to the Ajax request. The response is more likely to be a JSON dump of `$errors` or the result information.

Since the logic is stored in include files you can put it on a separate URL and still get easy access to all the shared logic.

That said, it would be a little more RESTful to use the same URL and add an addition bit of `if/else` to do different things based on the `Accept` header (i.e. test to see if JSON is prefered over HTML as the response).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah as you've said both options will work. But best practice is to use seprate file for AJAX calls, they are called as Web services/APIs.

They are made for doing some specific tasks.

So create new file for AJAX request and perform a single specific task from this file and return appropriate data as JSON/HTML.

This way you keep the main file's logic and form's logic separate and there won't be chaos in main **PHP** file.